# Raise event when boolean variable change his state

Tags: sql, vb.net, events, boolean, plc

I'm comunicating a Mitsubshi PLC with a "cheap handmade" HMI that we build in ViualBasic.

I need to track the value of a boolean variable in the PLC memory in my VisualBasic HMI, we achieve this by using an OPC server. No major complications in this step.

Next, I have to write the state of this variable in a SQL Database, when this variable change his state, something like:

```
If MyVar Changes from 0 to 1 Then
    Write "True" in SQL (1 entry)
End If

If MyVar Changes from 1 to 0 Then
    Write "False" in SQL (1 entry)
End If
```

My problem is that I don´t know how to catch the change in the state of the variable without constantly polling it. This means that I'm constantly adding entries to my SQL database, but i only want 1 entry per variable change of state.

Comment: Have you considered noting the state of the variable, in another member variable, and only adding the database entry when it differs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class to track the value of your Boolean:

```
Public Class BooleanWithEvent

    Private _value As Boolean

    Public Event ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Public Property Value
        Get
            Return _value
        End Get
        Set(value)
            If _value <> value Then
                _value = value
                RaiseEvent ValueChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

You can create an instance of this class and add an event handler:

```
Public WithEvents MyBoolean As New BooleanWithEvent

Private Sub MyBoolean_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBoolean.ValueChanged
    Select Case MyBoolean.Value
        Case True
            ' Write "True" in SQL (1 entry)
        Case False
            ' Write "False" in SQL (1 entry)
    End Select
End Sub
```

---

EDIT

A more elaborate version which tracks unlimited amount of values and fires a single event:

```
Public Class BooleanValuesWithEvent

    Private _values As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Boolean)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Occurs when a value has changed.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="index"></param>
    Public Event ValueChanged(index As Integer)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets a default value.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property DefaultValue As Boolean = False

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets a value.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="index"></param>
    Public Property Value(index As Integer) As Boolean
        Get
            If _values.ContainsKey(index) Then
                Return _values.Item(index)
            Else
                Return DefaultValue
            End If
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            If _values.ContainsKey(index) Then
                If _values.Item(index) <> value Then
                    _values.Item(index) = value
                    RaiseEvent ValueChanged(index)
                End If
            Else
                _values.Add(index, value)
                RaiseEvent ValueChanged(index)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: Exellent ! It works !! One last question, if I want to do this for several variables, for example myboolean 1, 2, 3, ..., n ... Can be done in a compact way ? Like only 1 event that triggers for several variables...  Sorry if this is a noob question hehe

Comment: Yes, you can modify the class to handle an array instead.

Answer (score 1):

Most industrial protocols work by the request-response system and the only way to know that a variable has changed is by constant polling.

There are other protocols that work through the publish-subscription method, with them you can receive an update every time the variable changes, without having to do polling.
Two protocols that support this system are MQTT (via a broker) and OPC UA subscriptions.

I don't know if that OPC server you use is UA and if it supports subscriptions, maybe you should check it out.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to research this